# Setting tool tip text horizontally

Tags: java, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically I want my tool-tip text to be displayed horizontally with a background color of yellow. FYI I use bootstrap tool tip.

Here is the current code for for the tool tip text:

```
<c:choose>
   <c:when test="${fn:length(product.description) gt 56}">
     <div class="description-wrapper" data-toggle="tooltip" dataplacement="bottom"title="${product.description}">${product.description}</div>
   </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
     <div class="description-wrapper">${product.description}</div>
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

And here is the jQuery code:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
    </script>
```

Currently for the above code, the tool tip displays the text in a vertical manner as shown in the pic:

[image]

So I need to get two things done: I need to make the tool-tip text box and the text to be shown in a horizontal manner with a width greater than its height, if it makes sense, basically like a rectangle. Secondly I want the background color to be yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.tooltip-inner {
  width: 300px; /* width of tooltip */
  background: #999; /* you can add custom color here */
}

.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
  border-top-color: #999; /* you can add custom color here */
}
```